# In SQLServer, why doesn't granting object permissions add the user to db properly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, permissions

This is my setup:

- SQL server 2005
- UserA already setup as user on the server but not on databaseA.
- GRANT Execute ON [GetOrders] TO [UserA] AS [dbo]

As you can see, i have missed out a step.  I haven't added UserA to the database yet.  This doesn't fail and lets me grant execute on the object.

I believe in 2000 it would have thrown an error and not allowed me to do this.

Now, I have all these objects with the correct permissions set but the users cannot see the database.  To resolve this i have to remove the users from the database, re-add them properly and then give permissions.

Why is this allowed and is there a way to either prevent it or have it create the db login automatically whenever a new user is given object permissions.

thanks.

Comment: I'm receiving an error when I try to do this on a 2005 server in a database that is set to 2005 compatibility. I'm more of a SQL developer than a DBA, so maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

This is the part throwing you off.

> TO [UserA] AS [dbo]

Ditch the "as dbo" part.  It's granting the right to the dbo user.  Without the "AS [dbo]" part it will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably allowed to give DBAs the flexibility to modify the users and permissions when the database is not attached to your production server.  I don't believe you have to re-add the users.  Take a look at this guy's script: http://www.lazycoder.com/weblog/2007/06/04/re-associate-sql-users-with-logins/

Comment: I've tried the sp_change_users_login and it doesn't do anything:
The number of orphaned users fixed by updating users was 0.
The number of orphaned users fixed by adding new logins and then updating users was 0.